# Printing / Calculating values in un-interpreted function

Tags: z3

I have an un-interpreted function whose value is calculated by some constraints.

The model given by Z3 contains these statements -

```
  (define-fun matrix!2 ((x!1 Int) (x!2 Int)) Int
    (ite (and (= x!1 0) (= x!2 5)) 10
    (ite (and (= x!1 1) (= x!2 5)) 11
    (ite (and (= x!1 0) (= x!2 1)) 1
    (ite (and (= x!1 0) (= x!2 2)) 3
    (ite (and (= x!1 0) (= x!2 3)) 5
    (ite (and (= x!1 0) (= x!2 4)) 7
      0)))))))

  (define-fun k!0 ((x!1 Int)) Int
    (ite (>= x!1 0) (ite (>= x!1 1) 1 0) (- 1)))

  (define-fun k!1 ((x!1 Int)) Int
    (let ((a!1 (ite (>= x!1 3) (ite (>= x!1 4) (ite (>= x!1 5) 5 4) 3) 2)))
      (ite (>= x!1 1) (ite (>= x!1 2) a!1 1) 0)))

  (define-fun matrix ((x!1 Int) (x!2 Int)) Int
    (matrix!2 (k!0 x!1) (k!1 x!2)))
```

Now, I would like to see what are the actual values of 
`(matrix 0 0), (matrix 2 0), (matrix 2 2)` etc.

Question :

1. How to print the values using SMT2 format?
2. Is it possible / easy to print it using C API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the following?

```
(declare-fun m05 () Int)
(declare-fun m15 () Int)
(assert (= m05 (matrix 0 5)))
(assert (= m15 (matrix 1 5)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Comment: ah yes thanks ! :)
just a question that does this affect the performance of the sat solver? suppose if I have to see like 200 variables like this?

Comment: There should be no performance problem. I expect Z3 is clever enough to "divide & conquer" the problem as it can be nicely split up into separate sub-problems. Just give it a try!

Comment: We can also use the `eval` command. Example: `(eval (matrix 0 0))`